# Good Starting Material for a SEMI Beginner

Tags: digital-communications

I come from a hardware background and I am wanting to get myself more involved with the digital signal processing side of things.

I understand a lot of concepts, but only through application meaning I don't understand a lot of the theory.

If anyone could point me in the direction of some nice material that I could read over that can help me get a grasp on the basic material I would appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Signal Processing First _ McClellan

Very readable introduction to signal processing.

- Signals and Systems_Haykin

Probably the most readable undergraduate book on signals and systems.

- Signals and Systems_Oppenheim

Classical text on upper undergraduate Electrical Engineering introduction to signals and systems. Not an easy read but definetely worth it. However, it's very critical to find a solutions manual for benefiting from this book.

- Discrete-Time Signal Processing_Oppenheim

Formal introduction to the subject matter. Find a solutions manual.

Comment: Hey Fat32. Thanks for the answer! I'll be sure to check these out!